# Proper ultimate way to migrate JMS event listening to Spring Integration with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I got a `JmsConfig` configuration class that handles JMS events from a topic in the following way:

- It defines a `@Bean ConnectionFactory`, containing an ActiveMQ implementation
- It defines a `@Bean JmsListenerContainerFactory` instantiating a `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` and passing it through Boot's `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer`
- It defines a `@Bean MessageConverter` containing a `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` and setting a custom `ObjectMapper`
- I use `@JmsListener` annotation pointing to myfactory on a method of my service. This is the only use I have for the topic, subscription alone.

Now I want to move to **Spring Integration**. After reading a lot, and provided I don't need a bidirectional use (discarding *Gateways*) neither a polling mechanism (discarding *`@InboundChannelAdapter`*), I am going for a `message-driven-channel-adapter`, in traditional XML configuration wording. I found that Java idiom should be accomplished by means of the new Spring Integration DSL library, and thus, I look for the proper snippet.

It seems `JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` is the proper equivalent, and I found a way:

`IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(...))`

But the problem is that this only accepts the ActiveMQ ConnectionFactory or an `AbstractMessageListenerContainer`, but no my boot pre-configured `JmsListenerContainerFactory` !

How should this be implemented in an ultimate way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JmsListenerContainerFactory` is specific for the `@JmsListener`, it's a higher level abstraction used to configure a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. Boot does not provide an auto configuration option for a raw `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`; you have to wire it up yourself. But you can still use the Boot properties...

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
                            JmsProperties properties) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(container(connectionFactory, properties)))
            ...
            .get();
}

private DefaultMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
                                                  JmsProperties properties) {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(properties.getListener().getConcurrency());
    container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(properties.getListener().getMaxConcurrency());
    ...
    return container;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is even a better approach. I am surprised Gary did not comment it.
There's an out-of-the-box builder called `Jms.container(...)`.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsMyServiceMsgInboundFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageConverter jmsMessageConverter, MyService myService, JmsProperties jmsProperties, @Value("${mycompany.jms.destination.my-topic}") String topicDestination){

      JmsProperties.Listener jmsInProps = jmsProperties.getListener();

      return IntegrationFlows.from(
                                Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(  Jms.container(connectionFactory, topicDestination)
                                                                     .pubSubDomain(false)
                                                                     .sessionAcknowledgeMode(jmsInProps .getAcknowledgeMode().getMode())
                                                                     .maxMessagesPerTask(1)
                                                                     .errorHandler(e -> e.printStackTrace())
                                                                     .cacheLevel(0)
                                                                     .concurrency(jmsInProps.formatConcurrency())
                                                                     .taskExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
                                                                     .get()))
                                   )
                                   .extractPayload(true)
                                   .jmsMessageConverter(jmsMessageConverter)
                                   .destination(topicDestination)
                                   .autoStartup(true)
                                    //.errorChannel("NOPE")
                             )
                             .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG)
                             .log()
                             .handle(myService, "myMethod", e -> e.async(true).advice(retryAdvice()))
                             .get();
```