# Spring Integration Transform Failure rolling back JMS and not forwarding to error channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

using Boot 2.2.2 and Integration 5.2.2 - when an XML message is sourced from a `File` and fails unmarshalling (i.e. it is not XML) the message proceeds as expect to `errorChannel`. However, when the message comes from JMS, through the same route of channels and fails unmarshalling, it is **not** routed to `errorChannel` and the message is rolled-back to JMS. After which I am stuck in an endless loop of `SAXParseException` for the same message.

I had following this example from [Proper ultimate way to migrate JMS event listening to Spring Integration with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887651/proper-ultimate-way-to-migrate-jms-event-listening-to-spring-integration-with-sp)
 . Is there some implied transaction control that I am not considering? How do I have Spring Integration forward the message to `errorChannel` and commit the 'get' from the incoming queue?

Synopsis of code is as follows;

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReader() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                Files
                    .inboundAdapter( ... )
                    ...
                    .get(), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000))
            )
            .transform(new FileToStringTransformer())
            .channel("backUpChannel")
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow getMessageFromJms(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, @Value("${queues.myQueue}") String myQueue) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Jms
                .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                .destination(myQueue)
        )
        .channel("backUpChannel")
        .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow doBackUp() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("backUpChannel")
            .<String>handle((payload, headers) -> {
                String uuid = headers.get(MessageHeaders.ID).toString();
                File backUpFile = new File("c:/backup/" + uuid + ".txt");
                byte[] payloadContent = payload.getBytes();
                try {
                    java.nio.file.Files.write(backUpFile.toPath(), payloadContent);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return payload;
            })
            .channel("XXX")
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        unmarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(MyClass.class);
        return unmarshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow handleParseXml() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("XXX")
            .transform(new UnmarshallingTransformer(unmarshaller()))
            .channel("YYY")
            .get();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.errorChannel(...)` to the message-driven channel adapter.

Comment: Thanks for respondin. I should had paid more attention to section 23.2.1 in the reference doc. I just assumed it applied to payload conversion in the JMS call, not further down the flow.

Comment: If you detect a transient error, the error flow can throw an exception and the message will be requeued.